# How to replace ChildFragmentManager with Navigation Graph in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation-graph

I'm working on nested fragment scenario where I'm using a fragment with `BottomNavigationView` and inside that main fragment I need to load new fragments and these new fragments should replace more fragments within main fragment what contains `BottomNavigationView`. I'm able to load main fragment using `NavigationGraph` but not child fragments.

[image]

I'm loading main fragment as

```
    <navigation -------    >
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainTabFragment"
    android:name="com.package.MainTabFragment"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_tab"/>
    </navigation>
```

And for Child fragments I'm using fragment manager as:

```
  private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment): Boolean {
    //switching fragment
    childFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit()
    return true
  }

MainFragmentGraph:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/nav_landing_graph">

<!-- region added graphs  -->
<include app:graph="@navigation/nav_landing_graph" />

<include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_main_tab" />
<!--  endregion  -->


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainTabFragment"
 android:name="com.package.ui.mainTab.bottomView.MainTabFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_tab">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_landingFrag_to_bottomViewFrag"
        app:destination="@id/nav_graph_main_tab" />
</fragment>

</navigation>
```

`nav_graph_main_tab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main_tab"
app:startDestination="@id/mainTabFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainTabFragment"
    android:name="com.package.ui.mainTab.bottomView.MainTabFragment"
    android:label="@string/my_health_space"

    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_tab">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_bottomViewFrag_to_mainFrag"
        app:destination="@id/nav_menu_graph" />
</fragment>

<include app:graph="@navigation/nav_menu_graph" />

</navigation>
```

It would be great if someone can help me to replace it with `NavGraphComponent`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace the fragments and not add the new fragment above the old fragment?

Comment: Also please add your complete navigation graph

Comment: @Kartik Updated both navigation graphs. Child one is not working for me.